# What is a standard way to save a location in a list between application runs?

Tags: python, inspect

I’d like to make a simple application which shows one element from a list on screen at a time (using curses). The user navigates left and right with keys. They can close the application with q.

The application should remember where they were when they reopen the application. This is a simple question, but is the most standard application architecture to store application-state related information in a single file called “application.data”?

Comment: What is regarded as standard practice for this sort of thing is platform-dependent. I don't think II've ever seen a file called `application.data`on Windows; but Windows does have a *folder* addressable via the environment variable `APPDATA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serialize the application data and store it in a file. you can try using xml or json. the file extension should be "application.dat" not "application.data"

Comment: What structure do larger applications have? A directory of multiple data files?